# why is my github copilot not working all of a sudden?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, github-copilot

I have been using copilot for a while now, and one fine day on opening VSCode this error appeared.

"[ERROR] [default] [2022-04-09T08:38:10.995Z] GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: "certificate has expired"

I looked up for it everywhere and found nothing, it'd be a great help if someone could fix this for me!

[here's the error and how the extension looks like on the status bar]

Comment: Are you logged into GitHub?

Comment: yes i am, tried logging in and out too

Comment: I have the same problem just with PyCharm, all of a sudden it is not working

Answer (score 51):

Three common causes:

1. An out of date IDE. Solution: **make sure your IDE is up to date**
2. If you're not properly signed in to GitHub CoPilot. Solution: **make sure you're signed in to GitHub CoPilot**

E.g. In VSCode look on the bottom left, if you see this, you might not be signed in:

[image]

Click the icon, and follow the prompts to sign in, then CoPilot should work.

3. Try closing and reopening your IDE (e.g. vscode), that may also help.

Comment: I had to restart VSCode as well

Comment: Find GitHub Copilot in VSC extension, click settings icon, and check Add to workspace recommendation. This is my final resort.

Comment: Ignored his comment that the certificate has expired. what certificate? Useless answer.

Comment: Step 3 fixed it for this alma Linux user

Comment: I was signed in to 2 accounts at the same time. I didn't even know that was possible. Signing out of the account that isn't signed up for Copilot fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 24):

I know its a bit late. But I encountered this problem today. If disabling and restarting doesn't help, you could try:

[At uninstall, select Install another version, and select the version before the latest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVlI7.png)

[Reload vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1irL.png)

After doing this, my copilot started working again.

Comment: Thanks man it's working fine after installed the previous version of copilot

Comment: it seems that using the latest version that just came out (17 December at 4 am ET) solves this issue for me! They solved the bug I think

Comment: Changing to the previous version of Copilot worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Two things you should check:

1=> Update VSCode to the latest version

2=> Update GitHub Copilot to the latest version (Enable it from the extension section)

After the update, it MAY require that you Reload/Restart VSCode.

From the Menubar, go to `View -> Output`;
Choose **GitHub Copilot** from the pulldown on the left to see the log of what is going on in the background.

Look at my pulldown here imgur.com/VVHfqwv

Comment: I did ```View -> Output```, but I don't see GitHub Copilot in any pulldown on the left.

Comment: Try to update the **GitHub Copilot** to the latest version and Enable it from the extension section. After the update, it MAY require that you Reload VSCode.
Look at my pulldown here https://imgur.com/VVHfqwv

Comment: After updating VSCode, it works again!

Answer (score 6):

Went to copilot extension settings and changed

```
    "github.copilot.enable": {

        "*": true,
        "plaintext": false,
        "markdown": false,
        "scminput": false
    }
```

to

```
    "github.copilot.enable": {

        "*": true,
        "typescript": true,
        "plaintext": false,
        "markdown": false,
        "scminput": false
    }
```

and it suddenly started working.  I may have opted to disable it for `typescript` in a GUI a day or two ago - if so that would indicate more state than what is seen in the settings.json file (?).

Comment: As time passed it happened again.  Checked the settings and the "typescript" property had disappeared.  Set it again and all was well.

Answer (score 4):

Go to your Github account and check if you have paid the bill, In my case that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Restart vscode thats it, it works for me post a restart.

Answer (score 2):

## Feb 2024

- Go to the copilot extension, on uninstall button there is drop down.
- Click on install another version.
- Switch to older version.
- Click reload. Done !

Comment: thanks, back working by installing pre-release version.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, if you are the one that disabled the Copilot before you can enable the following way.

**Either** search for "Copilot".
**Or** go to Tools>>Options>>GitHub>>Copilot

Go to Enable Globally and change from false to True.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All the above solutions didn't work for me.

What worked for me was opening VS Code as an "administrator". Then Github Copilot just started working ✅

Here's where I found that solution:
https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/6785#discussioncomment-1561804

Answer (score 0):

I had gotten to the end of the free trial, but had paid the sub, but it didn't work for me immediately.

However, the following steps got round that:

1. Uninstalled GitHub Copilot Chat and Github Copilot on VSCode
2. Signed out of my Github account on VSCode
3. Signed back in to my Github account on VSCode

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try: open the CoPilot extension and make sure it's **Enabled** and not **Disabled**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your settings:
   Go to `File > Preferences > Settings`
   and search for **"copilot"**.
2. Find the `Copilot:Enable` property and set the value from `*` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms. After logging out in VS Code I could not log in. The root cause was rate limit of Github API.

Answer (score 0):

On a mac?

Make sure VS Code is in the Applications directory.

My mistake was loading the wrong version:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Given that GitHub Copilot is so fresh and well-liked, updates are made often. When encountering this kind of problem, I would advise entirely purging and reinstalling.

**Installation of GitHub Copilot in Visual Studio Code**

The documentation lists extensions for Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio, Neovim, and the JetBrains suite as IDEs that GitHub Copilot supports.

> The installation consists of three main steps:
>
> 1. Create a GitHub account (if you don’t have one already).
> 2. Go to GitHub Copilot and click on “Start my free trial”. Follow the sign-up steps and make sure to cancel before your 60-day free trial is up (if you don’t want to continue using the tool).
> 3. Install the VSCode extension by searching for “GitHub Copilot” on the extensions tab. You’ll be asked to sign in to GitHub, authorize the extension, and then Copilot will be set up.

If you would like a more thorough explanation, my colleague Rafael wrote a great article based on his time with Copilot and VSCode: https://www.scalablepath.com/full-stack/ai-pair-programming-github-copilot-review